# How to use ISNULL result in a calculation involving a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, isnull

I have a SQL script that uses a subquery, the result of the subquery can sometimes be NULL so I've used `ISNULL` to set the result to zero (0) in those cases.

The problem I have to solve is that I need to use that zero in a calculation. The calculation is to see if the system has enough inventory of a specific item, so its basically:
Quantity In Stock - Quantity Needed = Balance

If the subquery returns 0 and qty. 8 is needed then the result should be -8 but currently the result will just show as 0 because of the `ISNULL` function.

```
ISNULL((
    SELECT
        SUM(ILE.[Remaining Quantity]) - CTE.[ExtendedQuantity] 
    FROM [Item Ledger Entry] ILE
    GROUP BY ILE.[Item No_]
    HAVING (CTE.[ItemNo] = ILE.[Item No_])
),0) AS [Balance]
```

I tried to use a case expression but wasn't exactly sure how to structure that with the subquery to make it work, it still may be possible.

**Current Result:**

| Item No. | Qty. In Stock | Qty. Needed | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 017030 | 0 | 8 | 0 |

**Desired Result:**

| Item No. | Qty. In Stock | Qty. Needed | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 017030 | 0 | 8 | -8 |

I think I need to modify how I'm using the `ISNULL` in some way just not sure what approach to try, please let me know if anything more is needed.

Comment: What's wrong with just putting `- [Qty. Needed]` needed after the expression? Why didn't that work?

Comment: put your whole query. Also, it's usually meaningless to just print the results of the wrong query, since we don't sit next to you and see the original data, better to provide some sample data

Comment: I think what you are actually trying to ask is how to use a calculated value in multiple columns... and the answer is `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: Also sample data and expected results would help. Your `HAVING` should probably be a `WHERE`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.[ask] [Help] (When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.) (Debug fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isnull()` should only applied to your subquery

```
ISNULL((
    SELECT 
        SUM(ILE.[Remaining Quantity]) 
    FROM  
        [Item Ledger Entry] ILE
    WHERE 
        CTE.[ItemNo] = ILE.[Item No_]
),0) - CTE.[ExtendedQuantity]  AS [Balance]
```

Comment: Yes that worked well and produced the result I needed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -2):

If the row is empty than you can wrap this around ISNULL.

```
   ISNULL((SELECT
        SUM( ISNULL(ILE.[Remaining Quantity],0)) - CTE.[ExtendedQuantity] 
    FROM [Item Ledger Entry] ILE
    GROUP BY ILE.[Item No_]
    HAVING (CTE.[ItemNo] = ILE.[Item No_])
),0) AS [Balance]
```

Comment: If no rows are found, this will result in `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**